# Windows Phone 7 Jump List Groups By Alphabetical Order

Tags: windows-phone-7, longlistselector, jump-list

I have a jump list which groups by individual entries but i wanted to group list by alphabets

```
var ANBA = from accountsTable in dataSource
           orderby accountsTable.Extra
           group accountsTable by accountsTable.Extra.Substring(0, 1) into c
           orderby c.Key
           select new Group<AccountsTable>(c.Key, c);

this.AccountsList2.ItemsSource = ANBA;
```

this code makes list with small letter & capital letter with different group

```
a
    ab
    ac
    ad
A
    Aa
    Ab
    Ac
```

How to make it where small letter & capital letter will be in same group & all the other characters in single group like all the numbers & characters

```
a 
    Aa
    ab
    ad
    AGDS
*
    1
    5000
    @@ASD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to modify the query to do that:

```
List<Table> Source = new List<Table>();

var ANBA = from accountsTable in Source 
                  orderby table.Extra
                   group table by (( table.Extra[0]>='a' &&table.Extra[0]<='z' )
                      ||( table.Extra[0]>='A' &&table.Extra[0]<='Z' ) ?table.Extra.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()[0]:'*')  into c
                   orderby c.Key
                   select new Group<Table>(c.Key.ToString(), c);

        this.ANListGropus.ItemsSource = ANBA;
```

Comment: I also just added a "order by" on extra so that subitems are sorted alphabetically also

Comment: hi the code which you updated is giving me error the code before this was working

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'App.Accounts.Group<App.AccountsTable>.Group(string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<App.AccountsTable>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Comment: Updated to add ToString in new Group<Table>(c.Key.ToString(), c);